# How to paste an HTML table into Libre Office Calc without losing structure

Tags: html, libreoffice, table

I want to paste an HTML table into Libre Office Calc. The HTML table rows contain images (in column 1) that should stay with their appropriate row. However, when I paste my HTML into Calc, the images are not pasted into rows but are free floating on the sheet. That prevents me from sorting the rows and doing the other spreadsheet operations I need to do on the table.

How can I get Calc to accept HTML table data structured like shown below and keep the table structure fully intact?

Example of a table (partial):

```
<table class="items">
<thead><tr class="top-labels">
<th class="empty">&nbsp;</th>
<th>Item</th>
</tr>
</thead> <tbody>
<tr class="item">
<td class="product-photo-cell"> <a
href="http://example.com/item1">
<img
src="http://cdn.example.com/350_thumb.jpeg"> </a> </td>
<td class="product-title-cell"> <a
href="http://example.com/item1">Super
Duper Item</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi! Did you find any solution to this? Even 2022 and LibreOffice can't accept formatted html table to parse. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in many versions.
Here is its [bug report](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=74577)
The solution is either to use a very old version 3.x, or to use the latest versions 7.4.x. or later. I suffered from the same bug myself on LibreOffice 7.0.0 and the bug disappeared after upgrade to LibreOffice 7.4.7.2.